# Kaazing fails when establishing connection

Tags: javascript, cordova, websocket, jms, kaazing

i'm using kaazing javascript jms library to establish a connection in our angular/cordova hybrid app. for the first time everyting works fine. then i kill the application and try to connect again. it just hangs and nevers calls the callback after createConnection:

```
  var future = factory.createConnection(function () { ..//do some stuff ... })
```

When I set the log-level to trace

```
 Tracer.setTrace(true);
```

I can see the following exception in chrome developer tools:

```
DF5963E0C7FF945789FBBD2CCD142D2F.cache.js:692 Uncaught Application Exception: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : $wnd.Connection is not a function
```

Did somebody experience the same?

Thanks Angela

Comment: Hello @puzste, can you confirm you are calling createConenction inside a "deviceready" listener.

"document.addEventListener("deviceready", yourCallbackFunction, false);"

Comment: Hello @hthetiot. I tried both, it doesn't matter if the create Connection is called from deviceready or not. The second time i start the application the calleback is never called...regards

Comment: Finally we solved the problem! The kaazing library had a name clash with the cordova plugin cordova-plugin-network-information which is a transitive dependency of phonegap-plugin-mobile-accessibility which we’re using.
The Connection object of the kaazing library is globally exposed ($wnd.Connection). The same name is used by cordova-plugin-network-information. To circumvent this, we replaced the variable Connection with KaazingConnection in the file DF5963E0C7FF945789FBBD2CCD142D2F.cache.js. I think kaazing should fix this!